# What tool to use to get/set Azure Blob cache-control property

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Is there a tool that properly handles getting/setting Azure Blob storage cache-control properties remotely?

I have tried Azure Storage Explorer v4 and v5 and Cerebrata Azure Explorer but they are not displaying cache-control information for a BLOB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops. Did more tests and Cerebrata Azure Explorer is properly handling cache-control.